# Load all records that contain `sym value from splayed tables in directory

Tags: select, load, subdirectory, kdb, q-lang

I have tables called; quotes, trades and sym saved as splayed tables in a directory called splay in my q directory.  I cannot figure out how to load these tables using the methods identified on the code.kx.com website.  When I check the file properties, it says file type is File, so I do not know what type of file to open after the filename.  Once I have managed to load these files, I need to select all records that contain the symbol IBM (in the column sym of the tables). I  have tried so far:

```
q)\cd splay
q)\l quotes
'quotes. OS reports: The system cannot find the file specified.
  [0]  (.Q.l)
q)\l trades
'trades. OS reports: The system cannot find the file specified.
  [0]  (.Q.l)

 .Q )\l trades.q
'trades.q. OS reports: The system cannot find the file specified.
  [2]  (<load>)

  ))\l trades.dat
'trades.dat. OS reports: The system cannot find the file specified.
  [4]  (.Q.l)
```

to no avail.  the same approach but for the directory itself.

```
q)\l splay
```

I have tried to just run the files without loading by being in the directory but this has also not been successful.

```
q)\cd splay
q)\cd
"C:\\Users\\Lewis\\splay"
q)t:get`:trades
'trades. OS reports: The system cannot find the file specified.
  [0]  t:get`:trades
         ^
q)q:get `:quotes
'quotes. OS reports: The system cannot find the file specified.
  [0]  q:get `:quotes
         ^
q)load`quotes
'quotes. OS reports: The system cannot find the file specified.
  [0]  load`quotes
       ^
```

One of the ways the code.kx.com website says to do this, and one of my first approaches:

```
C:\Users\Lewis\q>q/q.exe splay
KDB+ 3.5 2017.10.11 Copyright (C) 1993-2017 Kx Systems
w32/ 4()core . . .  

Welcome to kdb+ 32bit edition
For support please see http://groups.google.com/d/forum/personal-kdbplus
Tutorials can be found at http://code.kx.com/q
To exit, type \\
To remove this startup msg, edit q.q
'/q.exe. OS reports: The system cannot find the file specified.
  [0]  (.Q.l)

 .Q )
```

and the final approach I have had to load these files or directory is:

```
q)))load `splay
'splay. OS reports: Access is denied.
  [6]  load `splay
       ^
q))))\cd splay
q))))load `splay
'splay. OS reports: Access is denied.
  [9]  load `splay
       ^
```

Please, help me!

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the directory `/Users/Lewis` you should be able to pass the splay as a command line parameter, like this: `q splay`. There may be an issue with the path you are using to your q application `q\q.exe` which is causing an error to flag up.

Alternatively you should be able to open it from inside an active q session like: `\l splay` provided you are in the directory `/Users/Lewis` OR like `\l .` if you are in the directory `/Users/Lewis/splay`, where `.` is a shortcut for the current directory.

Additionally you stated that you have the tables `trade`, `quote` and `sym`. It all depends how you saved the data to disk but the `sym` file should not be a table like the other two, which you should see when you load the data in.

The error `OS reports: Access is denied.` is probably due to the q process not having appropriate permissions to access the file. If you start the process with admin privileges you should be able to get around this error.